# How to correctly escape array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, json, escaping

I want to escape an array in php

I try to escape with addslashes function but it doesn't work

```
 while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        $row['name']=addslashes($row['agente']); //escape ?
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
```

I want to escape the name of a person call 'Antonio cinà' but it doesn't work
The problem is 'à'

Comment: what gets outputted instead?

Comment: output : antonio cin?

Comment: "Escaping" is output dependant. Be less tight-lipped about what you want to accomplish, where the data originates, etc. For JSON-encoding, the charset is of significance.

Comment: PD of [UTF-8 all the way through](//stackoverflow.com/q/279170)

Answer (score 1):

You also use htmlspecialchars() instead of htmlentities() to escape the array string.

```
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    $row['name']= htmlspecialchars($row['agente']); //escape ?
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use htmlentities() php function to escape special characters.

```
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
        $row['name']= htmlentities($row['agente']); //escape ?

    }
```

[PHP Manual for htmlentities](https://www.php.net/htmlentities)

Comment: If you're outputting to HTML, sure.

Comment: I try but htmlentities clean the variable

Comment: I want to escape string and then convert to json all array